# Generator Expression for install() commands

Tags: cmake

The docs for CMake 3.2.2 state, that it is possible to use generator expressions for the `install(<FILES|PROGRAMS> ...)` signature. I was trying to use generator expressions in other signatures of `install()`, but apparently it is not working. I would like to do something like this:

```
install(TARGETS foo EXPORT fooConfig
        RUNTIME DESTINATION "Bin/$<CONFIG>"
        LIBRARY DESTINATION "Lib/$<CONFIG>"
        ARCHIVE DESTINATION "Lib/$<CONFIG>"
```

I also tried calling `install()` multiple times like this:

```
install(TARGETS foo EXPORT fooConfig
        RUNTIME DESTINATION "Bin/Debug" CONFIGURATIONS Debug
        LIBRARY DESTINATION "Lib/Debug" CONFIGURATIONS Debug
        ARCHIVE DESTINATION "Lib/Debug" CONFIGURATIONS Debug
install(TARGETS foo EXPORT fooConfig
        RUNTIME DESTINATION "Bin/Release" CONFIGURATIONS Release
        LIBRARY DESTINATION "Lib/Release" CONFIGURATIONS Release
        ARCHIVE DESTINATION "Lib/Release" CONFIGURATIONS Release
install(TARGETS foo EXPORT fooConfig
        RUNTIME DESTINATION "Bin/MinSizeRel" CONFIGURATIONS MinSizeRel
        LIBRARY DESTINATION "Lib/MinSizeRel" CONFIGURATIONS MinSizeRel
        ARCHIVE DESTINATION "Lib/MinSizeRel" CONFIGURATIONS MinSizeRel
install(TARGETS foo EXPORT fooConfig
        RUNTIME DESTINATION "Bin/RelWithDebInfo" CONFIGURATIONS RelWithDebInfo
        LIBRARY DESTINATION "Lib/RelWithDebInfo" CONFIGURATIONS RelWithDebInfo
        ARCHIVE DESTINATION "Lib/RelWithDebInfo" CONFIGURATIONS RelWithDebInfo
```

This causes CMake to emit an error along the lines of *Target 'foo' exported more than once in 'fooConfig'*.

I cannot use `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` here either without updating the CMake cache and re-running the build. Rather than that, I want to use the Visual Studio batch-build feature, which builds multiple configurations for me.

There was a little hack that I tried too. I noticed that CMake's generated `INSTALL` project is simply invoking a CMake script `${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/cmake_install.cmake` with the argument `-DBUILD_TYPE=$(Configuration)`. So I tried the following:

```
install(TARGETS foo EXPORT fooConfig
        RUNTIME DESTINATION "Bin/\${BUILD_TYPE}"
        LIBRARY DESTINATION "Lib/\${BUILD_TYPE}"
        ARCHIVE DESTINATION "Lib/\${BUILD_TYPE}"
```

This actually worked well for the installation. However, the installed export script, i.e. the output of `install(EXPORT fooConfig DESTINATION .)` now also tries to use `${BUILD_TYPE}`, which is not set at the time the user includes that script...

If anyone knows another way to accomplish my goals, please let me know.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unluckily the `install` command only supports generator expressions for the list of files to be installed, but not for the destination directory.

I would recommend on sticking with your little hack, but use `CMAKE_INSTALL_CONFIG_NAME` instead of `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE`, i.e.:

```
install(TARGETS foo EXPORT fooConfig
        RUNTIME DESTINATION "Bin/\${CMAKE_INSTALL_CONFIG_NAME}"
        LIBRARY DESTINATION "Lib/\${CMAKE_INSTALL_CONFIG_NAME}"
        ARCHIVE DESTINATION "Lib/\${CMAKE_INSTALL_CONFIG_NAME}"
```

`CMAKE_INSTALL_CONFIG_NAME` is set to the actual build configuration used for installing in the generated `cmake_install.cmake` script.

The generated export scripts (e.g., `fooConfig-debug.cmake`) can be automatically fixed by adding a patch script to the installation process. Generate a file `patch_export_files.cmake` with the following contents in the source directory:

```
file(GLOB_RECURSE _configFiles "$ENV{DESTDIR}${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/fooConfig-*.cmake")
foreach(_configFile ${_configFiles})
    file (READ "${_configFile}" _contents)
    string (REGEX MATCH "configuration \"[A-Za-z]+\"" _configName "${_contents}")
    if (_configName MATCHES "\"([A-Za-z]+)\"")
        message(STATUS "Patching: ${_configFile}")
        string (REPLACE "\${CMAKE_INSTALL_CONFIG_NAME}" "${CMAKE_MATCH_1}" _patchedContents "${_contents}")
        file (WRITE "${_configFile}" "${_patchedContents}")
    endif()
endforeach()
```

The patch script need to be run at installation time by adding an `install(SCRIPT ...` call after the `install(EXPORT ...`:

```
install(EXPORT fooConfig DESTINATION .)
...
install(SCRIPT patch_export_files.cmake)
```

The patch script first parses the configuration that the generated export script is valid for from its header comment and then replaces each use of `${CMAKE_INSTALL_CONFIG_NAME}` with the configuration name.

Comment: I expected that I had to do something like this... It's a shame CMake does not support something like this. In their issue tracking system I have seen that they implemented generator expressions for the DESTINATION arguments of all install() signatures recently, but there is no official release with this feature yet. So for future users: recent versions of CMake (>3.2.2) probably already support generator expressions for other signatures than install(FILES).

Comment: Note that as of Cmake v3.4, you can use generator expressions for the destination.

Answer (score 2):

I am working on a project which requires builds with different configurations. The way I have achieved this is using "ExternalProject".

I have created a sample repository to show you the idea:
https://github.com/mpaluru/cmake_multiple_build_configs_example

(Linux is the environment I use mostly and don't have access to Visual Studio.)
If you pass on the -G flag in the top level CMakeLists.txt, you should be able to generate your VS files. I have tested this on Linux and "make -j" works fine. Both the Debug and Release configurations build in parallel.

Summary:
You create a new superbuild project which calls your project using ExternalProject_Add with different CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE.

And based on the build type, you pass different definitions, or do install differently.

Comment: ExternalProject is a good idea, but this would require me to change an existing source tree, right?

Comment: NO and YES. It depends on how your current project is configured. If you have already taken care of doing things different based on the variable CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE, you don't need to modify the existing project at all. All you do is create a new wrapper project as I pointed in the example code.

Comment: But this wrapper project would have to live outside the existing code, at least one level above the original source root. Or is there some way to incorporate this wrapper directly in the root? Maybe via multiple inclusion?

Comment: Yes that's correct. You can get it to work at the same level, but it might be a little too hacky.